# Magento: Reference Error: Sizzle is not defined prototype.js

Tags: jquery, magento, prototypejs

I am using firefox.

During working I could see that my magento site is throwing a javascript error:

```
Reference Error: Sizzle is not defined prototype.js


})(Sizzle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the prototype with the latest version.

And its solved.

I had 1.7; I replaced it with 1.7.1

Comment: Unfortunately 1.7.2 seems to have broken this again (updating Sizzle is in the changelog for 1.7.2).

See https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/issues/203 for the bug in Prototype's issue tracker.